# how to get ssl certificate details using python

Tags: python, request, urllib

I am using the following code to validate the ssl certificate status, Can we get more details about certificate like common name (CN),expiry date and issuer using request module or urllib

```
import requests

def check_ssl(url):
    try:
        req = requests.get(url, verify=True)
        print url + ' has a valid SSL certificate!'
    except requests.exceptions.SSLError:
        print url + ' has INVALID SSL certificate!'

check_ssl('https://google.com')
check_ssl('https://example.com')
```

Comment: Check out [How can I retrieve the TLS/SSL peer certificate of a remote host using python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7689941/how-can-i-retrieve-the-tls-ssl-peer-certificate-of-a-remote-host-using-python)

Comment: thanks for the update, this is based on openssl, hence it wont connect via web proxy that's the reason i am looking something like request module

Comment: I think [this link can help you.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30862099/how-can-i-get-certificate-issuer-information-in-python)

Answer (score 9):

```
import socket
import ssl
import datetime

domains_url = [
"devnote.in",
"devnote_wrong.in",
"stackoverflow.com",
"stackoverflow.com/status/404"
]

def ssl_expiry_datetime(hostname):
    ssl_dateformat = r'%b %d %H:%M:%S %Y %Z'

    context = ssl.create_default_context()
    context.check_hostname = False

    conn = context.wrap_socket(
        socket.socket(socket.AF_INET),
        server_hostname=hostname,
    )
    # 5 second timeout
    conn.settimeout(5.0)

    conn.connect((hostname, 443))
    ssl_info = conn.getpeercert()
    # Python datetime object
    return datetime.datetime.strptime(ssl_info['notAfter'], ssl_dateformat)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    for value in domains_url:
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        try:
            expire = ssl_expiry_datetime(value)
            diff = expire - now
            print ("Domain name: {} Expiry Date: {} Expiry Day: {}".format(value,expire.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"),diff.days))
        except Exception as e:
            print (e)

#Output :

Domain name: devnote.in Expiry Date: 2020-11-11 Expiry Day: 46
[Errno -2] Name or service not known
Domain name: stackoverflow.com Expiry Date: 2020-11-05 Expiry Day: 41
[Errno -2] Name or service not known
```