# how do I get ssl certificate of site in python with proxy?

Tags: python, sockets, ssl

I need to get a detail information about ssl certificates of different sites and I need to use proxy. I found similar questions like this: [how to get ssl certificate details using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41620369/how-to-get-ssl-certificate-details-using-python) but they all are using sockets which does not provide an easy interface for proxy manipulation. Is there a more high level library, that would allow me to use proxy or may be some tutorial on how to use sockets with proxy that is applicable in my case?

Answer (score 0):

python_socks library did the trick. Full code using it:

```
import ssl
from python_socks.sync import Proxy
from datetime import datetime


def get_cert_expiry_date_with_proxy(hostname, proxy):
    ssl_dateformat = r"%b %d %H:%M:%S %Y %Z"
    proxy = Proxy.from_url(proxy.replace("https://", "http://"))
    sock = proxy.connect(dest_host=hostname, dest_port=443)
    context = ssl.create_default_context()
    context.check_hostname = False
    sock = context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=hostname)
    request = f"GET /ip HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: {hostname}\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n".encode("utf-8")
    sock.sendall(request)
    ssl_info = sock.getpeercert()
    return datetime.strptime(ssl_info["notAfter"], ssl_dateformat).date()
```