# Python3 SSL: SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE

Tags: python-3.x, ssl, openssl

Pretty straight forward. I'm trying to do some SSL Handshake and get the endpoint certificate from `sslsocket` documentation: [do_handshake](https://pythontic.com/ssl/sslsocket/do_handshake). Instead, I greeted with this specific error:

```
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/ssl.py", line 1342, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE] sslv3 alert handshake failure (_ssl.c:997)
```

The certificate will be used to extract any `SubjectName` or `CommonName`. Been looking around with 100 chrome tabs, busting my memory only for browsing. I have tried many steps:

```
# Monkey Patch to use Unverified Context
ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context

# Disable SSL Verification
sslContext.check_hostname = False
sslContext.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE

# Using Custom Ciphers
cipher = (':ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DES-CBC3-SHA:AES256-SHA:AES128-SHA:AES128-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES256-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3:EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3:EECDH+AESGCM:EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:EDH-AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:ECHDE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECHDE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECHDE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256+EDH:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-A$:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!3DES:!MD5:!PSK')
sslContext.set_ciphers(cipher)

# Using Custom OpenSSL Config

openssl_conf = openssl_init

[openssl_init]
ssl_conf = ssl_sect

[ssl_sect]
system_default = system_default_sect

[system_default_sect]
Options = UnsafeLegacyRenegotiation
```

None of them that able to fix the issue. Here's my current modified script based on `sslsocket` documentation

```
import socket
import ssl
import platform
import time

cipher = (':ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DES-CBC3-SHA:AES256-SHA:AES128-SHA:AES128-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES256-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3:EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3:EECDH+AESGCM:EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:EDH-AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:ECHDE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECHDE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECHDE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256+EDH:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-A$:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!3DES:!MD5:!PSK')
ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context

sslContext = ssl.create_default_context()
sslContext.check_hostname = False
sslContext.set_ciphers(cipher)
sslContext.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE

clientSocket = socket.socket()
secureClientSocket = sslContext.wrap_socket(clientSocket, do_handshake_on_connect=False)

t1 = time.time()
retval = secureClientSocket.connect(("example.com", 443))
print("Time taken to establish the connection:%2.3f"%(time.time() - t1))

t3 = time.time()
secureClientSocket.do_handshake()
print("Time taken for SSL handshake:%2.3f"%(time.time() - t3))

serverCertificate = secureClientSocket.getpeercert()
print("Certificate obtained from the server:")
print(serverCertificate)
```

My Setup

```
openssl version
OpenSSL 3.0.7 1 Nov 2022 (Library: OpenSSL 3.0.7 1 Nov 2022)

python3 --version
Python 3.10.8
```

I'm in desperate situation, anyhelp is highly appreciated.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem with your code. Are you really testing against example.com or do you use another target domain? Also note that getpeercert will be empty if you disable certificate validation. And you might get the wrong certificate since you don't give the expected `server_name` in wrap_socket and thus no SNI is used.

Comment: Yeah, I've been noticing. Disabling SSL Verification because of desperation. I have test it against list of Domains and the result is the same @SteffenUllrich

Comment: Moving the Environment from WSL to Windows, the script works but does not print any certificate (it's empty). @SteffenUllrich

Comment: *"the script works but does not produce print any certificate (it's empty)"* - this is expected as you disabled certificate validation. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45478536/python-getting-common-name-from-url-using-ssl-getpeercert on how to deal with this

Comment: *"Moving the Environment from WSL to Windows,"* - interesting detail. Do things like curl work in WSL for this specific sites? If they do, could you provide the output for `curl -v https://example.com` ?

Comment: @SteffenUllrich .Curl is working as intended but it is very long, I can't put it here: https://pastebin.com/v1XFLsN7

Comment: So this does not look like some SSL interception done from some antivirus then. Strange then that curl works in WSL, Python does not but Python works in the underlying plain Windows. Unfortunately I have no access to WSL for testing myself.

Comment: Sorry for late responses. Since it doesn't work on WSL, I'm thinking to experimenting with TLS.  Is there any reference to do TLS Connection without involving local server? I wanted to purely use TLS Connection against google @SteffenUllrich

Comment: *" Is there any reference to do TLS Connection without involving local server?"* - I'm not sure what you are asking. Isn't that what you are doing already? What kind of reference you expect apart from the ssl documentation in Python?

Comment: I wanted to inititate connection only on TLS Level without involving proxy. For example, I can explicitly add `server_hostname = domain` on `wrap_socket` and use only that without `socket.connect((domain, 443))` which falls into a proxy level. @SteffenUllrich

Comment: Finding a similar approach in Python to `go`-lang `tls.Client()`, where you can just initiate handshake without the need of `tls.Server()`: https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/crypto/tls/tls.go @SteffenUllrich

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251134/discussion-between-steffen-ullrich-and-xavi).